# Chemical software for solving reactions

Tags: reaction-mechanism, software

I'm looking for a software which can solve chemical equations. For example something like this (given with result):

\begin{align}
    \ce{CH4 + 2O2 & → CO2 + 2H2O} \\
    \ce{C3H6 + HCl & → C3H7Cl}
\end{align}

Is there are such software? I'm studying chemistry as a hobby and want to check if I'm doing the reactions correct.

Comment: I'm sorry, but this question is of the "make-a-list" type and thus needs to be closed. Please read the [faq] before posting :)

Comment: Other questions like this one were not closed and seem to be helpful, see: http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/24/1208 Why not re-open this question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no such thing as chemical reaction are not that easily predictable. You can get result right in some cases, but it is impossible to count all factors.