# Given advancements of computational power an machine learning, how is it still not possible to predict products from chemical reactions?

Tags: reaction-mechanism, everyday-chemistry, experimental-chemistry, computational-chemistry, machine-learning

Given that it seems every answer to this question is that it is "impossible to predict the outcome of a chemical reaction." Is chemistry just trial and error? Given how fundamental and revolutionary a simulator capable of predicting possible outcomes of a reaction would be, why has it not been done yet? Do you think it will ever happen?

Comment: A useful computational method like CCSD(T) scales with $N^7$. Even if the Computers get more and more power, those methods will aways be extremely expensive

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Software for predicting chemical reactions](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/8351/software-for-predicting-chemical-reactions)

Comment: This isn't necessarily a duplicate if one focuses on the machine learning aspect.

Comment: @penta Then that would make the question off-topic for *other* reasons O:)

Comment: @paracetamol I disagree. Machine learning now plays a large role in chemistry, and can predict reaction outcomes. See https://dx.doi.org/10.1021/acscentsci.7b00064 for just one of many examples.

Comment: @pentavalentcarbon, Great article! Thanks for sharing.

Comment: Machine Learning does not circumvent the computational complexity of the problem. In other words, ML doesn't transform the traveling salesman problem from NP-complete to P, unless P=NP. A product prediction routine has to explore all possible reaction pathways between all possible stable compounds, which grows exponentially with the number of atoms. Or at least find all convex stability regions and evaluate the thermodynamics correctly, which still explodes combinatorially.

Answer (score 2):

It's not an all-or-nothing situation, where either we can reliably prediction reaction products, or we have not tried to.

For instance, drug companies, for many years, have been making extensive use of increasingly powerful, sophisticated, and refined *in silico* predictive models to choose likely candidates for *in vitro* testing.  And I would be surprised if they've not also begun to develop, evaluate, and incorporate ML.

At the same time, these models are not perfect.  So the answer is that it is being done, it's been done for a while, we're getting better and better at it, but we still have a long way to go.

It will be interesting to see what happens with quantum computing, which is currently in its infancy.